# Python - Regex (Re.Escape, Re.Findall); How To: Find sub-strings + a number of characters beyond the sub-strings within a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, findall

This might be an simple question.  I'm learning how to use Regex and I am having trouble performing a specific task on a string.

For example:

example_string = "; One, one; Two, two; Three, three; Four, four"

desired_output = ["One, o", "Two, t", "Three, t", "Four, f"] #list output is OK

With the following, i can get ["One" , "Two" , "Three"]:

```
def findStringsInMiddle(a, b, text): 
    return re.findall(re.escape(a)+"(.*?)"+re.escape(b),text)

desired_output = findStringsInMiddle('; ' , ',' , example_string)
```

But I am having trouble figuring out how to configure this properly to grab the comma+space+any_type_of_character that I also want.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.  Everyone's solution actually worked so I had to base the solution that I picked on some other metric.  Wiktor's answer configured the actual function that I had which was what I asked specifically and he was the first to do that.  Anyways, all of the answers below are great: I'm sorry that I can't pick them all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may re-organize the pattern a bit by including the right-hand delimiter and appending an optional `(?:\s*.)?`  group:

```
def findStringsInMiddle(a, b, text): 
    return re.findall(re.escape(a)+"(.*?"+re.escape(b) + r"(?:\s*.)?)",text, flags=re.S)
```

The pattern will look like `;(.*?,(?:\s*.)?)` (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yFYsU3/2)) and will match:

- `;`  - the left-hand delimiter
- `(.*?,(?:\s*.)?)` - Group 1:

  - `.*?`  - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `,` - a comma
- `(?:\s*.)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of 0+ whitespaces and then any char.

Note I added `re.S` flag to make `.` match line break chars, too.

Seee [full Python snippet below](https://ideone.com/sHidg6):

```
import re
example_string = "; One, one; Two, two; Three, three; Four, four"
desired_output = ["One, o", "Two, t", "Three, t", "Four, f"] #list output is OK

def findStringsInMiddle(a, b, text): 
    return re.findall(re.escape(a)+"(.*?"+re.escape(b) + r"(?:\s*.)?)",text, flags=re.S)

desired_output = findStringsInMiddle('; ' , ',' , example_string)
print(desired_output)
# => ['One, o', 'Two, t', 'Three, t', 'Four, f']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the full pattern (from semi-colon to the second letter after the comma) and mark the group you want to extract:

```
>>> s =  "; One, one; Two, two; Three, three; Four, four"
>>> re.findall(r"; (.*?,.{2})", s)
['One, o', 'Two, t', 'Three, t', 'Four, f']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution:

```
example_string = "; One, one; Two, two; Three, three; Four, four"
def findStringsInMiddle(text): 
    return re.findall("; (.+?, [a-z])",text)

desired_output = findStringsInMiddle(example_string)
desired_output
```

Output:

```
['One, o', 'Two, t', 'Three, t', 'Four, f']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

example_string = "; One, one; Two, two; Three, three; Four, four"

pattern = re.compile(r";\s"  # The search string must start with a semoicolon and then a space character
                     r"([A-Z][a-z]+,\s.?)"  # Here is the capturing group, containing first a capital letter,
                     # some lowercase letters
                     # and finally a comma, space and zero or one characters
                     )
print(re.findall(pattern,
                 example_string
                 )
      )
```

Output:

```
['One, o', 'Two, t', 'Three, t', 'Four, f']
```